# Default text box value to change on load

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have created text box and while submit I am able to get the 123 values thats fine.when I enter the new value(567) in text box and submit the values I am able to see the changes in view .but still the text box is showing 123.Instead of 567.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())

 <input type ="text" name = "id" value="123" />


   <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> </p>

}
```

Comment: You are showing `123` statically, it should be the value from database or something else...

Comment: Yes the static value is from db only so I have passed one default value. If user wants to check the result with another value and submit the view has to change. But while on load again the default value is in text box. Instead of user entered value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the value attribute of textbox on success of submit

```
document.getElementByName("id").value = your_updated_value;
```